# cxf Spring Maven dependency conflict

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, cxf

Our project is using the following cxf dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

We are using the latest `cxf 2.6.1`. However, the `cxf-bundle` lib is dependent on `Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE` libs, which is conflicting with our `Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE` libs, which is required to understand our annotation based ORM config classes.

Does anyone have a good solution for resolving this?

Comment: It's a Bad Thing to use two versions of the same lib in the same build. Pick one. Do you want the latest CXF or your ORM classes? (Can you update your ORM classes to work with Spring 3.1?)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the Spring dependencies to your required version have to set the them explicit in your pom, like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>lorem</groupId>
  <artifactId>ipsum</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This will resolve to:

```
...
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
...
```

Why do you depend on cxf-bundle? Are you running in an OSGi environment?

The cxf-bundle imports the packages

```
 org.springframework*;resolution:=optional;version="[2.5,4)"
```

It should be OK if the latest Spring version is deployed in the container (at least I would try it).

Comment: I actually did explicitly specify the Spring versions just as you did. However, I'm getting a mix of Spring lib versions after Maven resolves all dependencies. For example, I'm getting `spring-beans:3.0.7.RELEASE` and `spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE`. To be honest, I'm not sure why `cxf-bundle` is included. I'm not quite familiar with CXF. We inherit this component from another project. But we will not be deploying this in an OSGI env for sure.

Comment: What I'm seeing in the spring config is: `<!-- CXF Specific Setup --> 
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />`.

Comment: I took out `cxf-bundle` and tried to deploy the project in Tomcat. I got `13:30:39.548 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.c.c.spring.ConfigurerImpl - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.CXFBusLifeCycleManager.
13:30:39.564 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.c.c.spring.ConfigurerImpl - Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerRegistryImpl.`

Comment: I took that back. I forgot to update all Spring dependencies to 3.1.2.RELEASE. Now they are updated. But now I'm getting `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL`. Seems that cxf does not like Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE.